# Linux script text substitutions

Tags: bash

I want to make a few configuration files (for homeassistant) that are very similar to each other. I am aiming to use a template file as the base and put in a few substitution strings at the top of the file and use a bash script to read the substitutions and run sed with the applicable strings.
i.e.

```
# substitutions
# room = living_room
# switch = hallway_motion
# delay = 3

automations:
  foo......
  .........
  entity_id: $switch
```

When I run the script it will look for any line beginning with a `#` that has a word (key) and then an `=` and another word (maybe string) (value) and replace anywhere that key with a `$` in front is in the rest of the file.
Like what is done by esphome. https://esphome.io/guides/configuration-types.html#substitutions

I am getting stuck at finding the "keys" in the file. How can I script this so it can find all the "keys" recursively?
Or is there something that does this, or something similar, out there already?

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you post some code, we can help you improve it.

Comment: I don't have anything substantial that I would build off of. I can use sed to find and replace. And I looked at a python script that does this for esphome. But I don't know how to do it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with sed in two stages.  The first stage will generate a second stage sed script to fill in your template.  I'd make a small adjustment to your syntax and recommend that you require curly braces around your variable name.  In other words, write your variable expansions like this:

```
# foo = bar
myentry: ${foo}
```

This makes it easier to avoid pitfalls when you have one variable name that's a prefix of another (e.g., `foo` and `foobar`).

```
#!/bin/bash
in="$1"
stage2=$(mktemp)
trap 'rm -f "$stage2"' EXIT
sed -n -e 's,^# \([[:alnum:]_]\+\) = \([^#]\+\),s#\${\1}#\2#g,p' "$in" > "$stage2"
sed -f "$stage2" "$in"
```

Provide a filename as the first argument, and it will print the filled out template on stdout.

This example code is pretty strict about white space on variable definition lines, but that can obviously be adjusted to your liking.